# I want to release memory of mediaplayer to resolve memory issue

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

This is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listview;
    CustomListAdapter adapter;
    private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public static int currentItem;
    public static ArrayList<String> videoLIst;
    public static MediaController mediaController ;
    boolean pauseOnScroll = true;
    boolean pauseOnFling = true;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);
        System.gc();
         StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork().penaltyLog().build());
        videoLIst = new ArrayList<String>();
         mediaController = new MediaController(MainActivity.this); 
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/Home_Video/mov_bbb.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/experience/165/video/father-and-young-daughter.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/experience/185/video/couple-on-sail-boat.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/experience/39/video/VID-20141231-WA0006.mp4");
        videoLIst.add("http://journey.coderspreview.com/uploads/experience/26/video/VID-20141216-WA0004.mp4");
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listview.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
        listview.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, videoLIst));
        listview.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
         listview.setRecyclerListener(new RecyclerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMovedToScrapHeap(View view) {
                    VideoView videoView = (VideoView)view.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

                }
            });

      listview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
          private int mFirstVisibleRow = -1;
          private int mActiveItem = -1;

          @Override
          public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
               VideoView videoView = (VideoView)view.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
               if (scrollState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_FLING) {
                   videoView.destroyDrawingCache();
               } else {
                   videoView.buildDrawingCache();
               }
          }


          @Override
          public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                               int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
              int firstVisibleRow = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
              if( mFirstVisibleRow != firstVisibleRow )
              {
                  mFirstVisibleRow = firstVisibleRow;

                  // Cancel the video of the previous active item
                  VideoView prevActiveVideoView = getVideoViewForRow(mActiveItem);
                  if( prevActiveVideoView != null )
                  {
                      prevActiveVideoView.pause();
                      prevActiveVideoView.destroyDrawingCache();
                  }

                  // Start the video of the new active item
                  mActiveItem = mFirstVisibleRow + 1;
                  VideoView newActiveVideoView = getVideoViewForRow(mActiveItem);
                  if(newActiveVideoView != null)
                  {
                      newActiveVideoView.start();
                      newActiveVideoView.buildDrawingCache();

                  }
              }
          }

          private VideoView getVideoViewForRow(int row)
          {
              int firstVisibleRow = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
              View rowView = listview.getChildAt(row-firstVisibleRow);
              return (rowView == null) ? null : (VideoView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
          }

      });

    }
    static class ViewHolderItem {

                TextView textViewItem;
                VideoView video;
                ProgressBar progressbar;
            }

    public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Activity activity;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private ArrayList<String> videoList;

        public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> videoList) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.videoList = videoList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return videoList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int location) {
            return videoList.get(location);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


             final ViewHolderItem viewHolder;


             if (convertView == null){
                  inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list_item, null);

                   viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
                   viewHolder.video = (VideoView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
                   viewHolder.progressbar = (ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progress);

                   viewHolder.textViewItem =(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txvposition);


                   int pos;
                   pos=viewHolder.video.getCurrentPosition();
                   Log.d("current item position:",""+pos);
                    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

             }else{
                viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();

             }

             viewHolder.textViewItem.setText("Video"+position);
//             mediaController.setAnchorView(viewHolder.video);
             Log.d("video url inadapter:", ""+videoLIst.toString());
             Uri uri = Uri.parse(videoList.get(position));
            // viewHolder.video.setMediaController(mediaController);
           //  viewHolder.video.setVideoURI(uri);
             new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                 @Override
                 public void run() {
//                   viewHolder.video.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                   viewHolder.video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     viewHolder.video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoList.get(position)));
                     viewHolder.video.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                }
            }, 1500);
             //viewHolder.video.start();
             viewHolder.video.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                     public void onPrepared(final MediaPlayer arg0) {
                           viewHolder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                           viewHolder.video.start();
                           viewHolder.video.setBackgroundResource(0);
                           arg0.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                mp.release();

                            }
                        });

                     }
                   });
             viewHolder.video.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener() {
                      @Override
                       public boolean onInfo(final MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         Log.d("BUFFRRING START", "On_InFO");
                         if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_START == what) {
                               viewHolder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                             Log.d("BUFFRRING START", "" + what);
                         }
                         if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BUFFERING_END == what) {
                               viewHolder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                               Log.d("BUFFRRING END", "" + what);
                         }
                         if (MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_RENDERING_START == what) {
                               viewHolder.progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                               Log.d("RENDERING END", "" + what);
                         }
                         return false;
                       }
                   });
              viewHolder.video.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

                       @Override
                       public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                           // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                           Log.d("Error", "------>error" + what + "/" + extra);
                           if (extra != 0) {
                               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Can't Play Video",
                                       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           }

                           return false;
                       }
                   });
              viewHolder.video.clearAnimation();
              return convertView;           
        }

    }
}
```

when app run first time it is ok but when I scroll listview video which is set in last item display in first item position for few times after that correct video according to my arraylist item display I think I have release memory or clear memory to clear mediaplayer but where I set this code I have no idea and due to this issue may be listview scroll not work smoothly how I resolve this issue?

I am little bit confused what I release videoview or mediaplayer?

Comment: why you are not using hashmasp to maintain  video Sequence......

Comment: sequence is ok only for few sec when I scroll listview video I played last display as first after that video according to sequence displayed me means old video displayed me before newer start to play so memory was not cleared how I cleared this?

Comment: can please attach screen shot..... as per my understndng  you have list view which contain Videos ... right... then 1st video plays successfully  but when 2nd  video starts you are getting 1st Videos Image....

Comment: see I have 5 video to play in listview first time it is in sequence but when I scroll listview fifth vedio display as a first video for few sec after that first one display at same position got it?

Comment: I am not working on emulator how i add screenshot from my device I have no idea.

Comment: Press Volume Down + Power Button .... together

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84172/discussion-between-nidhi-dave-and-koutuk).